# Codeigniter Active Query: Multiple Update same column different row different Where ID

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

Having spent several hours and numerous google search, i still couldn't get this solve.
Kindly help check what i am doing wrong in this code:

```
               $product = $this->site->getProductByID($item['product_id']);
                $inventory = $this->site->getInventoryByID($product->id);

                if($pp_up === TRUE && (($product->quantity < 0) && ($product->parent_id != 0) &&  ($inventory->box_qty != 0)) === TRUE ){

                $s_Update = array(
                    'quantity' => ($product->quantity+$inventory->qty_per_box),
                     'id' => $inventory->ea_id
                    );
                   $this->db->where('id',$inventory->ea_id);
                   $this->db->update('products',$s_Update);

        // the query runs successfully up till here------------------------------------

            /*This Never perform any update */
                  if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){

    $this->db->update('products', array('quantity' => ($product->quantity-1), array('id' => $inventory->box_id)));
```

the first update works successfully and update the table according. however, the second update has not effect on the table.

Please help with right direction.

I really hope this is really clear enough to get me assistance on this.

Thanks guys.

Comment: what is the data type of quantity field in your table Is it not integer?

Comment: quantity is varchar not integer

Comment: put this  $sql = 'update products set quantity ='.($product->quantity-1).' where id ='.$inventory->box_id; before the update query and echo this sql to see  what the output is

Comment: there is also a possibilty where update query not finds any id corresponding $inventory->box_id , Check the table

Comment: Ok. I will try that. But there is corresponding $inventory->box_id in the inventory table which was insert through products table

Comment: Ya ok but check this the value $inventory->box_id has, is also available in the product table or not. Suppose $inventory->box_id = 123 so check products table's id = 123 is present in the products table or not

Comment: did you echo the $sql given before .It is to check that  the update query  falls in  affected_rows condtion or not

Comment: Yes  $inventory->box_id has a corresponding id in production table.

Comment: Should i put the $sql query before the second update or i should use the method for the second update ?

Comment: just put it after affected_rows() conditions before the update. You can comment the update query

Comment: I did. But still the same. The second update never happen.

Comment: is $sql echo the query or not

Comment: No output. I did echo on $sql but i didnt get any output. Is there any way i can combine those query into one since i am updating the same table but different row and different row id. Please help. Lemme know if i need to show more of the code. In addition: i am doing this in codeigniter model. Thanks

Comment: in $s_Update array you have id field also and then updating the table by using that id it may be the problem, use the code i have given in my answer

Comment: look at this condtion  ($pp_up === TRUE && (($product->quantity < 0); here this condtion follows when quantity will be less than zero , If it is already less than zero then further subtraction results a negative number

Comment: and note that after the first updation you are not fetching data from products table so that quantity for the second update have the previous value that is less than zero

Comment: You are the best. I thought as much. I was wondering how to fix that. But i will try and get a fresh $product->quantity after the first update. I will let you know what i get. Thanks brb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do This ;**

```
 $s_Update = array('quantity' => ($product->quantity+$inventory->qty_per_box));
 $this->db->where('id',$inventory->ea_id);
 $this->db->update('products',$s_Update);

 $quantity = $product->quantity-1;
 $data = array('quantity'=> $quantity);

 $this->db->where('id', $inventory->box_id);
 $this->db->update('products', $data);
```

Comment: This perform the two update but there error. Instead of subtracting 1 from the $product->quantity where id = $inventory->box_id, it just insert "-2" to the quantity column. i have tried with several ids with varying $product->quantity in the table. same issue. (insertion of -2).

Comment: I have accepted this as an answer. It works. However, i just had to fetch $product->quantity again after the first update using $inventory->box_id and that end the heachaches. Thanks boss for pointing me to the right direction.